# How to preserve implicit key name typing as a part of an interface while still specifying the value type in TS?

Tags: typescript

I'd really love to be able to define an interface / type of an object that allows me to define what the values will be, but use the keys of the object as the set of possible keys, in the type. Visualized, I want to find an alternative to:

`interface IElementType = {[key: string]: SpecialProperties}`

and replace with something like

`interface IElementType = {[key: keyof elements]: SpecialProperties}`

in an example like

```
const elements: IElementType = {
  pirate: {
    name: 'patchy',
    type: 'matey'
  },
  captain: {
    name: 'peggy',
    type: 'pegleg'
  },
  ...
}


// for reference
interface SpecialProperties {
  name: string,
  type: string
}
```

where `keyof elements` is me making up what I wish were possible (knowing this can't work since `elements` is a js object) but am hoping I'm just thinking about it incorrectly. The motivation here is to preserve type info / intellisense when importing this variable into another part of the project. I can then type `elements.pirate` and ts will know that this key exists. When we use `[key: string]` we are effectively anonymizing the keys in the object and throwing that information away. As opposed to when we define the variable without any explicit type like

`const elements = { ... }`

where ts implicitly types this variable with a type that contains the explicit keys that the object contains, so in the case above, the type would exactly match the value of the full object.

I'm hoping there is some middle ground here where we can preserve the implicit typing of the key names but enforce their values to be specific. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can *express* what you're saying, since `keyof typeof elements` is a perfectly valid type, but you wouldn't be able to define `IElementType` in terms of `elements` and vice versa without getting circularity warnings:

```
type IElementType = Record<keyof typeof elements, SpecialProperties>;
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type alias 'IElementType' circularly references itself.
const elements: IElementType = { /* .. */ }
//    ~~~~~~~~ <-- 'elements' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
```

So we'll have to give up on that idea.

---

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `elements` with a type that does not already know about the specific keys, such as `{[k: string]: SpecialProperties}` with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), then the compiler will *widen* `elements` to that type and forget about the specific keys.

Since you'd like to be able to define `elements` in such a way that the compiler *checks* without widening it, then *you can't annotate it*.  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) asking for some type operator which acts like a non-widening annotation, but for now it's not part of the language.

Instead, you can define a generic helper function that you use instead of annotation.  You'd replace `const elements: IElementType = someValue` with `const elements = asElementType(someValue)`, where `asElementType()` is defined as:

```
const asElementType = <K extends PropertyKey>(t: { [P in K]: SpecialProperties }) => t;
```

This function will only accept an input if it can infer a key type `K` (which could be a union of keys) such that the input has keys `K` and values `SpecialProperties`.  Since the function just returns its input, the return type will be the same as its input: an object type with some inferred key types `K` and value types of `SpecialProperties`.

Let's see it in action:

```
const elements = asElementType({
    pirate: {
        name: 'patchy',
        type: 'matey'
    },
    captain: {
        name: 'peggy',
        type: 'pegleg'
    },
});
/* const elements: {
    pirate: SpecialProperties;
    captain: SpecialProperties;
} */
```

That works; now `elements` has the type `{pirate: SpecialProperties, captain: SpecialProperties}`.  And if you make a mistake, the compiler will warn you:

```
const oops = asElementType({
    swabbie: { // error! Property 'type' is missing
        name: 'bilgey'
    }
})
```

thus demonstrating that `asElementType()` acts similarly to an interface with dynamic key types but static value types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeAoXShSALgJ4zICSAogDYSTDEAq5yAvEgEoTxoBOAEwA8Aawik0AMxJtpSCPUbEoAGiQBlCvACWIWgAV+GCP2I7oAPgDcBIgHp7RAH6u3710mEBab0lYUSPp6WADkNEoQTAEQoUi6-PAArrQg-LSkSPwQUqZRiFg6KopSAHR2hHzAUMQKkUxQAFxIEQxRLGxInNhI9gBUSKWlSH1OAL4VvU4uHp4+fqGKbQ1xOljZudnAiIJIgjrZ8MQZSAJIOsD7h8eZF+cqpwDuwLKBIMDAaMQg5mjA5ZNHEgpGcNnlthBJhdiKYpAhkFpeHpDMYKGYLFg8ERsUhQJBmjV+BcAOaqSbYsgUAnEInAYmTCYTXBAkH8LI5cGIXDQ2HwzTaZFGEzo6A4SZ4iDU2mkyaUyVIQkk3ATKo1IJQOjLDqBTjCADSCgAHjDLlghWiyHqJJYABTEZo9ADaBnOLz1AF1mojdPpzaZzKKxgBKLqWEi2XCq2pLZRYTggDX1bUQG1YogwA4-eVpnG48Dy0JwYjwAAWpFCZNzhDlzVCYCz5YZlaI8BAMG+Fwd5KIEtrFGJxPLzdzNaQhYgxPoxNCTeVQds-XifzVMfaTTF2Iz-CzXoFvtR-oxtmxrfbIE7-KR++FAagtjGI3s+Ejy9qaAwcfVmuUMVTkygjwgAARkBFgOlMCj8MY-AAIRIH6ZiZKEcqrFgYBrFASpVnm+JjqBtDEhIM7YoyQbPkAA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! This makes a lot of sense and is technically exactly what I asked for. I do wish there a was a slightly cleaner way to do this in ts but this will certainly do for now. Without duplicating info this seems like the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

For this example...

```
const elements: IElementType = {
  pirate: {
    name: 'patchy',
    type: 'matey'
  },
  captain: {
    name: 'peggy',
    type: 'pegleg'
  },
  ...
}
```

...to work, define `IElementType` as a generic interface, but using `interface` declaration doesn't work in this case. :(

```
type IElementType<K extends string> = ​{
  ​[x in K]: SpecialProperties;
};
```

`elements` variable will be of type `IElementType<'pirate' | 'captain'>` for the first two keys.

Comment: Thanks for the response here - this is *almost* what I'm looking for and is a quite clean way to set things up but was hoping to achieve this without having to duplicate info by hardcoding the keys

Comment: If you've defined an object type or an interface, you can use `keyof` to get its keys, which should fit the type parameter, for example: `IElementType<keyof Element>`.